# Invalid redirect_uri in instagram oauth

Tags: python, django, instagram, django-allauth

I am using python django and django-allauth to implement oauth to instagram.
I think I have set all the required things in instagram app setting and got the application id and secret.
[image]

This is my app setting and I have added in my project to work with this configuration.
This is my views.py

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialAccount


class ConnectInstagram(TemplateView):
  template_name = 'connect.html'
```

And connect.html file looks like this

```
{% load socialaccount %}
<a href="{% provider_login_url 'instagram' %}"> Connect with Instagram </a>
```

I have already registered `social applications` in django admin site with site and application id and secret.
This is my settings.py file

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pathlib import Path

load_dotenv()
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

INSTAGRAM_APP_ID = os.getenv('INSTAGRAM_APP_ID')
INSTAGRAM_APP_SECRET = os.getenv('INSTAGRAM_APP_SECRET')

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['41b3-107-155-105-218.ngrok-free.app']

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://41b3-107-155-105-218.ngrok-free.app']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # 3rd party
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.instagram',
    
    # installed app
    'crafter.apps.CrafterConfig'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]

SITE_ID = 1

ROOT_URLCONF = 'main.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'main.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.getenv('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('DB_PORT'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'instagram': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'user_profile',
            'user_media'
        ],
    }
}
```

After I login to instagram using the url in django, it goes to instagram oauth link but it says `{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Invalid redirect_uri"}`

Could anyone help me?
Appreciate.

Comment: You likely need to change the redirect uri in your django admin to match the oauth2 redirect uri you added in the instagram panel. These need to match in order for the system to work

Comment: @montudor Thank you for your reply. Could you let me know where i can set the redirect_uri on django admin?

Comment: I believe this is specific to django-allauth which I am not familiar with. This could be set in `settings.py`, it depends where the configuration takes place